# Table of contents indentation and tabbing

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I've got a document with paragraphs using the "Heading 1" - "Heading 3" tags. When I add in the table of contents the heading 1 tags at the bottom have a different tab spacing then the heading 1 tags at the top of the document. All are single tabs in the document.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Note the difference between #9 and #10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sdaZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of Tables of Contents is governed by the **TOC styles**. They set the tab and indent settings in a TOC. Here is the best article explaining it in more depth.

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#Appearance) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP

Here is a [video on modifying the TOC Styles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tCGHU3QxFE).

You need to move the tab settings. You may have to actually get to the Tabs dialog to do this. Some of your numbers take up just *that much* more space. Here is an article on Indentation with numbering. [Number Alignment](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NumberAlignment2007.htm#NumberedLists) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP
Here is one on [setting tabs](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/SettingTabs.htm), also by Suzanne.